# How to pass Props and setup a CART of selected item in REACT

Tags: reactjs, undefined, undefined-behavior, react-props, setstate

I am developing a simple food app.
Firstly, it will show dishDetails in **MenuComponent**

**I am Sending complete MenuComponent in which i want to get Particular dish Id and pass it to CartComponent(Child component of Menu) **like a Ecommerce website.**Where we will order a item and it appears on Cart.
.Please guide me i wasted my week on this error or bug

**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from "reactstrap";
import Cart from "./Cartcomponent";
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishDetail: null,
    };

    this.getDish = this.getDish.bind(this);
  }

  getDish(selectedDish) {
    this.setState({
      dishDetail: selectedDish,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          {this.props.dishes.map((dish, index) => {
            return (
              <Card className="col-xl-2">
                
                <img
                  height="30%"
                  src={this.props.dishes[index].image}
                  alt={this.props.dishes[index].description}
                />
              <button
                  className="text-white m-2 p-2 "
                  onClick={() => this.getDish(this.props.dishes[index])}
                ></button>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <Cart dishDetail={this.state.dishDetail} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Menu;
```

Comment: Do you want to know, how to implement the Card component?

Comment: if any changes in this code can done my job then it will be better.otherwise kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use index while populating dish from dishes list. Also you need to define key, as I don't know what are the properties/values of dish object, for now, I have used index as the key value, but pls replace it with some unique value from dish object.

```
import React from "react";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from "reactstrap";
import Cart from "./Cartcomponent";
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishDetail: null
    };

    this.getDish = this.getDish.bind(this);
  }

  getDish(selectedDish) {
    this.setState({
      dishDetail: selectedDish
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          {this.props.dishes.map((dish, i) => {
            return (
              <Card className="col-xl-2" key={i}>
                <img height="30%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.description} />
                <button
                  className="text-white m-2 p-2 "
                  onClick={() => this.getDish(dish)}
                ></button>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <Cart dishDetail={this.state.dishDetail} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Menu;

const Cart = ({dishDetail}) => {
    return <div className="search-block">{dishDetail}</div>;
};
    
export default Cart;
```

If props value is undefined in Cart component, pls debug your dishDetail state first in the parent component i.e. Menu Component. You can start debugging backward, for example, you can start with getDish method, check if onclick after setting state, if the state is setting properly. If it is not setting, check if the value in the argument is coming properly and hence on.

Comment: @urvashi Actually From Menu Component the problem is .It is not sending props to Cart component